# Alloy - Remove middle atom from tuple

Tags: tuples, relation, alloy

I currently have three atoms `class`, `pupil`, `grade` and a tuple `mark` in the format `class->pupil->grade`. How can I return a tuple in the format `class->grade` so that I can see the grades a specific pupil has got in each class as a class/grade binary relation? Assume there is only one pupil in the system. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I can imagine to achieve this is using set comprehension as follows:

```
fun getGrade[p:Pupil]: Class->Grade {
  {c:Class,g:Grade|c->p->g in mark}
}
```

Comment: I need a tuple in the form `class -> grade` though, is this possible?

Comment: Right, pardon me I misread the question. I edited the answer accordingly